# Get initial layered navigation state

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, layered-navigation

Is it possible in **Magento2** to get the initial state of the layered navigation even if there is some filter applied?

For example: I have a custom filterable without results attribute with three possible values: **A**, **B** and **C**. When I visit the layered navigation page the filters show as follow:

```
Custom attribute:
  A (1)
  B (2)
  C (3)
```

When I click on the link to filter products by value A, what I get is

```
Custom attribute:
  A Remove
  Remove All
```

What can I do to keep the initial state of the layered navigation instead of showing the applied filter?

Comment: I managed to do this using the method suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38869641/2439677